# Makefile Syntax: Static library lib$(library).a($objects)

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I'm updating some Makefiles to move from Make 3.81 to 3.82.  In multiple places, the original author used something like this to build static libs:

```
all: lib$(library).a($objects)
```

This seems to build each .o file in turn and insert it into the .a using ar:

```
g++ -O2 <snip> -o some_obj.o some_cpp.cpp
ar rv libsome_lib.a some_obj.o
etc...
```

This new make version, though, chokes with:

```
*** No rule to make target 'libsome_lib.a()', needed by 'all'
```

Am I safe to replace this shortcut with the way I'm used to doing this:

```
lib$(library).a: $(objects)
     ar -rs lib$(library).a $objects
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Looks like I need a better Makefile education.  Here's a larger excerpt from the original Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS += -O2 -g -Wall -Wunused-parameter \
    `pkg-config --cflags gthread-2.0 glibmm-2.4 gtkmm-2.4`

libs +=  `pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0 glibmm-2.4` -lc

%.d: %.cpp
    $(SHELL) -ec '$(CXX) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< \
                      | sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \
                      [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'
%.d: %.c
    $(SHELL) -ec '$(CXX) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< \
                      | sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \
                      [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'

from_sources = $(patsubst %.c,$(2),$(filter %.c, $(1)))  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(2),$(filter %.cpp, $(1)))

sources = $(shell cat sources.inc)
objects = $(call from_sources,$(sources),%.o)
depends = $(call from_sources,$(sources),%.d)

library = some_lib

.PHONY: all clean fresh

all: lib$(library).a($(objects))

clean:
    <SNIP>

if neq($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    include $(depends)
endif
```

When this runs under 3.81, I get all the .d dependences created, then make starts g++ing the obj files.  Under 3.82, I get the .d files but no .o and make fails with "***No rule to make..."

Comment: For completeness, do you mean GNU Make?

Comment: What the [call function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) is supposed to do. Note the way that = type  (as opposed to := type) variables bind late causing this to do interesting things. Too clever for my tired little brain.

Comment: GNU make isn't that hard once you find good examples to start with. With no prior knowledge of GNU Make, a quite complex makefile can be produced in less than half a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "archive member" syntax supported in gnu make.  It's a bit too intimate with the tools for my tastes, but there it is.  The original error may be caused by $(objects) being empty.  But I'm really not sure.  Here's some documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archive-Members

> 11.1 Archive Members as Targets
>
> An individual member of an archive file can be used as a target or
>   prerequisite in make. You specify the member named member in archive
>   file archive as follows:
>
> ```
>  archive(member)
> ```
>
> This construct is available only in targets and prerequisites, not in recipes! Most programs that you might use in
>   recipes do not support this syntax and cannot act directly on archive
>   members. Only ar and other programs specifically designed to operate
>   on archives can do so. Therefore, valid recipes to update an archive
>   member target probably must use ar. For example, this rule says to
>   create a member hack.o in archive foolib by copying the file hack.o:
>
> ```
>  foolib(hack.o) : hack.o
>          ar cr foolib hack.o
> ```
>
> In fact, nearly all archive member targets are updated in just this way and there is an implicit rule to
>   do it for you. Please note: The ‘c’ flag to ar is required if the
>   archive file does not already exist.

Answer (score 3):

Your way looks good, but there must be more to the old makefile if the old way worked at all.

Oh, and just for good form I'd suggest this:

```
lib$(library).a: $(objects)
     ar -rs $@ $^
```

**EDIT**
Don't feel bad about not understanding Make very well; it has quite a learning curve.

There is still not quite enough to go on here, but if `sources.inc` isn't too huge, you could try the following in 3.81 and 3.82 and look for differences:

```
experiment:
    @echo sources: $(sources)
    @echo objects: $(objects)
    @echo depends: $(depends)
```

The evidence so far is that `objects` is empty under 3.82, but if the `.d` files are being rebuilt under 3.82 that suggests that `depends` is *not* empty, which is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, but you have no explicit rule for converting something like `xyz.cpp` to `xyz.o`, which you may need for your sources before trying to inject their objects into the library. There *may* be a suitable implicit rule for this so check first.

The first question I'd be asking is: what happened to `$objects` that caused you to try and target `libsome_lib.a()` (i.e., with nothing between the parentheses) in the first place?

To be honest, I tend to avoid these encompassing rules as much as possible, preferring explicit statements of dependencies (unless there are a *lot* of dependencies, of course). Yes, I know it makes the makefiles larger and marks me as at least a partial luddite, but I prefer to have things that just work over things that work cleverly.

Cut'n'paste is one of the strongest tools in my toolbox :-)

Comment: Luddite! Luddite! Of course, the particular mechanism used here is completely new to me. I must go and read docs now...

Comment: Except that once you get gcc automatic dependency generation right, you never have to bother again with maintaining complex makefiles.

Comment: @Alex: Well, yeah. But I've encountered three different methods of automatic dependency generation before, and *this* one is new to me.