# Why does this makefile work with make 3.81 but not 3.82?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a very simple makefile to build a static library that has worked fine for years with GNU make version 3.81 but fails with version 3.82.

I have read up on the issues with backward compatibility and those issues do not appear to apply. I've also checked several posts here, such as [Makefile Syntax: Static library lib$(library).a($objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457013/makefile-syntax-static-library-liblibrary-aobjects) and [Makefile - to create a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603521/makefile-to-create-a-static-library?rq=1), but cannot find a solution.

Here's my makefile:

```
FILES = file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc

OBJ_FILES = $(FILES:.cc=.o)

libname.a: libname.a($(OBJ_FILES))
```

Under version 3.81 this compiles fine using built-in and implicit rules. 
Sample output

```
g++  -c -o file1.o file1.cc
ar rv libname.a file1.o
ar: creating libname.a
a - file1.o
```

but with version 3.82 it fails with

```
*** No rule to make target `file1.o)'
```

I've looked at the output of make -d and version 3.82 fails with

```
   No implicit rule found for `file1.o)'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `file1.o)'.
  Must remake target `file1.o)'.
make: *** No rule to make target `file1.o)', needed by `libname'.  Stop.
```

while version 3.81 continues without a hitch

```
Trying implicit prerequisite `file1.o'.
Looking for a rule with intermediate file `file1.o'.
 <snip>
Found an implicit rule for `libname.a(file1.o)'.
```

What gives? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`file1.o)'`: looks like it somehow included the closing bracket '`)`' in the filename/string.

Try listing the object files explicitly like `OBJ_FILES = file1.o file2. file3.o` or use a different way to replace `.cc` with `.o`.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it looks and I have no idea why. Using your suggestion has no effect. 3.81 looks for target file libname.a(file1.o) while 3.82 tries file1.o)! Makes no sense to me.

Comment: BTW, this is straight out of the GNU make manual. [11.2 Implicit Rule for Archive Member Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Archive-Update.html#Archive-Update)